# How to correctly give patterns for POD name in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using kubernetes for deploying applications, and

```
kubect logs
```

for logs viewing.
Redeployments are very often, so it's bit uncomfortable - to copy `pod` name each time to paste in log command(because end of pod name dinamically changes each time), e.g. below are commands for same application, after 2 deployments

```
kubectl logs -n=testns --since=1m testapp-2818008534-jx2vv
kubectl logs -n=testns --since=1m testapp-2818008534-xls93
```

So, I want to use one command, which will correctly "pick up" needed POD name each time we'r running the "`kubectl logs`".

But smth like

```
$kubectl logs -n=testns --since=1h $(kubectl get pods --namespace=testns | grep testapp)
```

returns an error, that we are not "giving" pod name, BUT that pod exists for sure:

```
error: expected 'logs (POD | TYPE/NAME) [CONTAINER_NAME]'.
POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command
```

So, how to correctly set this command, to use it every time we want to look at logs, without need to re-copypaste full POD name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

`kubectl get pods --namespace=testns | grep testapp`

You get something like:

`testapp-54d99599bc-g2gs4           1/1       Running   0          56m`

So this won't go well with logs command as it has some additional data which can not be understood by Kubectl. What you can do is:

`kubectl get pods --namespace=testns | grep testapp | cut -d' ' -f1`

Which will produce only name of the POD and then your log command should work.

Comment: even without checking I see its correct - tnx man! Im just did not fully understand that "get pods" return "full row"

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer should work in most cases but just in case try this alternate:

```
kubectl get po | grep testapp | tr -s ' ' | cut -d\  -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector ([label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/) query) to filter the pods :

```
kube logs -lapp.kubernetes.io/name=testapp --all-containers=true
```

Working with kubectl `v1.15.0`